# Woocommerce PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a lot of custom fields in my WooCommerce checkout, and I'm trying to display them all on the admin page.

The number of fields varies from user to user, therefor I need to figure out how many fields of the name "$order-billing_date_of_birth" there is.

```
$order-billing_date_of_birth1
$order-billing_date_of_birth2
$order-billing_date_of_birth3
```

...and so on

I thought maybe I could use a loop like this.

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= 100; $x++) {
    echo '<p><strong>'.__('Date of birth').'</strong>: ' . $order->billing_date_of_birth.$x . '</p>';
}
```

My question is: How do I combine the two "billing_date_of_birth" and "$x" to work as "$order->billing_of_birth1".

There's probably better ways to solve this as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is what you need to do

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= 100; $x++) {
    $prop = "billing_date_of_birth".$x ;
    echo '<p><strong>'.__('Date of birth').'</strong>: ' . $order->$prop . '</p>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I can't believe I didn't try that one ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example code to achieve the requirements.

Converting the Object to array and then finding the element.

```
<?php
$object = new StdClass;
$object->foo1 = 'Hey';
$object->bar1 = 'Friend';
$array_obj=(array) $object;
//var_dump( $array_obj );

$bar='bar';
$num=1;

echo ($array_obj[$bar.$num]);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something similar, applied to a class.

for example
list-group-item1
list-group-item2
list-group-item3

With this code

```
jQuery(function($) {
$('.list-group-item').each(function(i) {
   $(this).attr('class',"list-group-item"+i);
});
});
```